# What is the best method to compute project volatility in Real Option Valuation?

Tags: options, volatility, real-options

There are few methods like Copeland-Antikarov, Herath-Park, Cobb-Charnes etc. to compute project volatility, however these methods compute upward biased volatility. 
What is the best method I could use to compute project volatility for real option valuation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main approaches:

1. Comparables (depends on having an existing sample of similar project outcomes, which can be difficult to obtai [similar to historical volatility for stocks])
2. Simulation (when comparables, or rather enough of them, aren't available)

Here's a link to a paper that provides a technique for estimating volatility for real options:

http://new.vmi.edu/media/ecbu/cobb/EE4902.pdf

Generally comparables is the preferable approach in real options, provided that you have a large enough historical sample.  In most cases, however simulation is used as 'true' comparables are notoriously difficult to find en masse.

Comment: heres's another simulation approach(not only for correlated inputs, but with more math):
http://etd.auburn.edu/etd/bitstream/handle/10415/147/Han_Hyun_51.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: Do you happen to have a title/link of the first paper?  The link is dead.

Comment: I just clicked the link and the paper came up fine...  "ESTIMATING PROJECT VOLATILITY AND DEVELOPING DECISION SUPPORT 
SYSTEM IN REAL OPTIONS ANALYSIS"

Comment: Weird - still doesn't work for me.  In any case, thanks for the info.